# upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04, now desktop is not working

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 19.04

I have got a notif to upgrade Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04, after several minutes of the upgrading software doing its job, I was prompted to reboot my laptop which I did, them the Ubuntu desktop wasn't working, I was prompted to login and I entered my password then the desktop loads up and now I cannot launch anything or click on anything, even left mouse click, menu drop nothing, I switched to ttty5 and run apt updates, nothing was out of date, I also did do-release-upgrade which was loaded with upgrades, then afterwards I did a reboot to only face the same problem, I then switched back again to ctrl+alt+F1 and purged gnome packages by doing apt purge gnome* and then doing apt install gnome and that did not do anything so I suspected the gnome-tweaks tool was out of date because I was using some of the extension, I deleted the package and rebooted, nothing happened, I even logged in Gnome Desktop instead to Ubuntu Desktop in the login screen and it was having the same problem.

What should I do, i do not want to reinstall Ubuntu again...

Comment: How did you upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 19.04?   By default the upgrade paths from 18.04 LTS are to the next LTS (ie. 20.04 LTS after 20.04.1's release) OR to the next release 18.10 , so a direct jump should not occur unless you have fiddled with sources to cause it (as it's unsupported & untested). Did you do something to force the jump?  I would check your logs, and esp. sources as something was done to cause what occurred, as whatever was done to cause this skip-release would likely influence fixes needed, though the easy route is re-install (I'd use 'something else', no format)

Comment: I was minding my own business and then I got a notification from software updater saying that a new upgrade is available so I upgraded,

Comment: I suspect you'd polluted your sources with cosmic ones (to get later programs) and thus had inadvertently turned your 18.04 LTS system into 18.10 (which then caused the 19.04 upgrade msg to show), so I would check your sources as 18.04 has no *cosmic* (18.10) sources and you shouldn't find any.  I would reboot & @tty `sudo apt update` (looking at msgs as scroll to see what's there; remove non-official sources then update again), then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` until 0 to upgrade. I'd then reboot & hope. You could look thru logs to see what occurred, but it'll take time; re-install is quicker